# Getting IndexOutOfBounds exceptions with Arraylist in a Loop

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception, wordle-game

I am making a game similar to [*Worldle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wordle).

I am trying append input to an `Arraylist` each time the loop executes.

While also trying to keep the format of wordle (`testnum` and `testnum2`). I am quite new to java and do not know why I am getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

[image]

*My code:*

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        int testnum = 6;
        int testnum2 = 1;
        int aaa = 0;
        String guess;
        ArrayList<String> inputs = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] wordList = { "CHARM", "UNITE","BRAVE", "ADIEU", "ROBOT", "FORGE" };
        String randomWord = wordList[(int) (Math.random() * wordList.length)];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int a=0; a<6; a++){  /*columns*/
          for(int j=0; j<5; j++){  /*rows*/
            System.out.print("- ");
          }
          System.out.println();
         }
        
        while(i<6) {
         System.out.println("Enter Guess: ");
         guess = input.nextLine();
         for(int a=0; a<6; a++){  /*columns*/
          for(int j=0; j<5; j++){  /*rows*/
            System.out.print("- ");
          }
          System.out.println();
         }
         if(guess.toUpperCase().equals(randomWord)) {
            System.out.println("Guessed");
            i++;
            break;
         }
         for(String hi : wordList) {
             if(guess.toUpperCase().equals(hi)) {
                 inputs.add(guess);
                 i++;
                 System.out.print("Incorrect Guess. Tries Left: ");
                 System.out.println(6 - i);
                 for (int aa = 0; aa<testnum2; aa++) {
                     System.out.println(inputs.get(aaa));
                     aaa+=1;
                 }
                 testnum -=1;
                 testnum2 +=1;
                 for(int a=0; a<testnum; a++){  /*columns*/
                  for(int j=0; j<5; j++){  /*rows*/
                    System.out.print("- ");
                  }
                  System.out.println();
                 }
             }
         }
         if(guess.length() < 5) {
             System.out.println("Not enough letters. Please try again: ");
         }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the exception and identify the line of code which is failing.

Comment: You should always add the full stack trace to your question. As far as I can see the only line that could throw that error is `System.out.println(inputs.get(aaa));`. So you need to debug it and see why `aaa` is getting too large.

Answer (score 0):

after some testing I found a solution.

My error was in

```
for (int aa = 0; aa<testnum2; aa++) {
       System.out.println(inputs.get(aaa));
       aaa+=1;
                 }
```

I changed it to:

```
for (int aa = 0; aa<testnum2; aa++) {
        aaa = aa;
        System.out.println(inputs.get(aaa));
}
```

The error was the aaa incremented after it got accessed, so I did it before and set it equal to aa.

Comment: The names are very poor, and you've crammed too much logic into a single method. Consider splitting it simple and concise parts extracted into separate methods with self-explanatory names.